# SQL If one column has a desired value then check the next column

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Name  SCRE_TXT  SRCE_NBR
MAX    PHONE          10
MAX    EMAIL          20
MAX    ADDRESS        90
MAX    PHONE          88
MAX    PHONE          30
MAX    EMAIL          21
MAX    PHONE          30
```

How would I check if the SRCE_NBR is distinct for only the rows with phone in it. Otherwise don't check SRCE_NBR at ALL.

Desired output would be

```
Name  SCRE_TXT  SRCE_NBR
MAX    PHONE          10
MAX    EMAIL          20
MAX    ADDRESS        90
MAX    PHONE          88
MAX    PHONE          30
```

Comment: I cannot match up your narrative to your sample data and desired output?, why is the `EMAIL, 21` row not included in the result?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever its just a simplified data set dont think too much into the actually data. I just only need one email and all the phones that have distinct SRCE_NBR

Comment: But your sample data and expected results don't seem to contain any of the features that you're asking for - e.g. no duplicates in the first place.

Comment: So I am considering both emails to be duplicates regardless of the srce_nbr and only care about srce_nbr when the row has PHONE in it.

Comment: "So I am considering both emails to be duplicates regardless of the srce_nbr " and "Otherwise don't check if SRCE_NBR is distinct. " ... So you are contradictory

Comment: Okay youre right edited to say otherwise don't check SRCE_NBR at all

Comment: So you don't care what src_nbr is returned for all non-phone scre_txts?   if so just min/max the srce_nbr and use a union like user1515791 started off with.

Answer (score 1):

Can you first select all the Phone rows, using distinct and then union that result with all the rows that are not Phone rows?

```
Select distinct * from ... where SCRE_TXT = 'PHONE'
UNION ALL
Select * from ... where SCRE_TXT <> 'PHONE'
```

Comment: Wouldn't this still display both emails? You would have to only look at two columns [NAME, SRCE_TXT ] on the        Select * from ... where SCRE_TXT <> 'PHONE' Which then gives me a incorrect number of result columns error

Comment: sure but just use `SELECT name, scre_txt, min(Src_nbr)...GROUP BY name, scre_Txt` if you only need one of each in the 2nd query.  but as your initial output showed both, that's why you get an answer like this.  it meets your expected results and why you need to spend time crafting a better more clear question.

Comment: Yeah, however, what should the criteria be for the email rows? The point is, just break it up in two sub queries that do match your needs and then union the results.

Comment: IMO this answer changing the 2nd select in the union to a `min(srce_nbr)` and a `group by name, scre_txt` meets the expected results.